# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning after upgrade from Angular 9 to 10

Tags: angular, migration, angular10

After updating to Angular 9 to 10 and run

```
ng serve -o
```

I got the following error

```
(node:34728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:407:11)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:548:9)
    .....
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\work\code\vespa-ui-service\vespa-web\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)(node:34728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:34728) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit cod
```

I also updated all other lib (eg primeNG) to the relevant version.
Building and unit testing the project won't return any error also.

So i wondering if I did anything wrong during migration process.

Comment: You are using a third party library that is ot compatible with Angular10, would be my guess

Comment: Seem like the --open package is having some issue.
Able to perform "ng serve" without the --open config